# An object is created without a method of a class. Typescript error: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2722)

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object, methods

Good evening! I am newbie in javascript and typescript.

I can't understand something. I carefully typed my code and the situation appeared. I can't imagine, why, through it's something basic. Look:

```
class A {
    id: number;
    constructor(id:number){
        this.id=4;
    }
    isIdZero?():boolean{
        if(this.id===0)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
}

let a : A= new A(0);
let b : A={
    id:9
}

alert(b.isIdZero());
```

This code makes an error "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2722)"

Why? Function equals to what typed in {}, isn't it?

How can I correct it?

My question is probably so primitive that I didn't find anything.

Comment: Well, `b.isIdZero` *is* `undefined` at runtime. What do you expect to happen there (ignoring all the TypeScript types)?

Answer (score 2):

```
isIdZero?():boolean{
```

The question mark here means you're defining `isIdZero` so it may be `undefined`, instead of being a function. Since it might be undefined, typescript won't let you call it unless you check it first. Eg:

```
if (b.isIdZero) {
  alert(b.isIdZero());
}
```

If you want `isIdZero` to be a mandatory property, then remove the question mark. However, this change will cause the following code to start showing a type error, since the object doesn't have all the properties it needs to be an A:

```
let b: A = {
    id:9
}
```

You can either add the function to the object you're creating

```
let b: A = {
  id: 9,
  isIdZero: () => false,
}
```

Or you can stop trying to call this an A, and just let it be an object with an id that's a number:

```
let b = {
  id: 9,
}
```

Comment: The problem is when I added this check, my program told me, that there is no such property! It's undefined! Or so in my original code, not in this example.

Comment: What should I do now???

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want all `A`'s to have an `isIdZero` function? Or for some of them to have it, and some not?

Comment: All of them should have this function, I added "?" because of some errors appeared whithout it. Originally it's function of validation of name and phone (I'm doing a phonebook)

Comment: K, start by making it mandatory by deleting the `?`. In most cases, you'll then just call `new A()` everwhere you need an `A`, and it will just work, as in your first line `let a : A= new A(0);`. If you do need to manually create an object that resembles an `A` (like you're trying to do on the second line), then you will need to add all the properties to it yourself. That includes adding an `isIdZero` property to it.

Answer (score 0):

the ? operator you are using after isIdZero? tells typescript that you expect a possibility of this property being undefined.

It doesn't seem like that's necessary, so you can remove that.

Comment: The problem is when I added this check, my program told me, that there is no such property! It's undefined! Or so in my original code, not in this example. 
What should I do now???